# remove inside information when merging two 3d objects

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, numpy-stl, pymesh

Hi i'm currently working on a project where we have to combine multiple 3d objects. So for example place them next to each other and some times they also intersect.

I'm looking for an algorithm/library or any idea that would reduce this new merged object to only consist of the outside faces. (Our 3d objects currently are .stl files but we are not bound to this format)

We've tried combining these objects with numpy-stl but it seems like this library does not have any optimisation that would help with this problem. We also tried using the boolean merge from pymesh but this takes very much time with detailed objects.

We want to loose all information that is inside the object and only keep the information that is outside. So for example if you would put this combined 3d object in water, we only want the faces that would be touched by the water.

We prefer python but any algorythm that could be implemented in python would bring us forward.

We appreciate every answer :)

Answer (score 0):

LibIGL appears to have Python bindings. I would suggest thresholding the ambient occlusion of each facet. For example, maybe delete all facets with an occlusion value higher than 0.8

https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/igl_docs/#ambient_occlusion

The inputs to this function are the vertices, the facet indexing into the vertices, the position of the facet centroids, and the normals for each facet. The output is the ambient occlusion for each facet, which is a value between 0 and 1. A value of 0 means the facet is fully visible, and a value of 1 means it is completely shadowed.

Comment: This looks like a good approach, but is apparently intended for rendering 3d objects. Does this work even if we want to have a 3D object as output (but without inner faces)?

Comment: I'm not following your question. Your concern is that the approach is intended for 3D objects and somehow that conflicts with your desire to have a 3D output?

Comment: My concern ist that the approach is intedet for rendering and I'm wondering if it would work when the output should be a 3d object and not an image

Comment: Although it is used in render processing, Wikipedia isn't quite correct when it refers to AO as a "rendering technique." The algorithm itself is not specific to rendering. I've used it pretty heavily in mesh reconstruction, surface forces computation, and physical optics. FYI, my use of AO for mesh reconstruction is nearly identical to the use-case you've presented here (removing meshes within other meshes)

Comment: That sounds promissing :)
I've been able to run the [example](https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/tutorials/#chapter-5-external-libraries) on one of my meshes but I'm confused now how i can actually find and remove the faces that have a brightness of 0.
I mean "ao" contains the information of the brightness but where is the link to the face?

Comment: The AO is output in the same order as the facets were input. Also, note that an AO value of 0 means the facet IS visible, whereas a value of 1 means it isn't.

Comment: So i came up with this [code](https://pastebin.com/KywUcpez) but it ony gets some bright faces and not all as you can see in this [image](https://pasteboard.co/J4UwEYm.png) It seems like it's the right way to go, maybe my [stl combination algorithm](https://pastebin.com/y5UA2a9C) isn't perfect you can find one stl [here](https://filebin.net/k6b5aecfk63qgjoa)(It's a 20*20*20 cube made of 8 10*10*10 cubes). I appreciate every advice and can't thank you enough for your help so far :)

Comment: I'm fairly certain the 3rd and 4th input of the ambient occlusion function should be the facet centroids (average of the 3 vertices of the facet) and the facet normals, not the vertices and vertex normals.

Comment: Hugh okay, they do it the same way in the [example](https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/tutorials/#chapter-5-external-libraries)
`n = igl.per_vertex_normals(v, f)

# Compute ambient occlusion factor using embree
ao = igl.ambient_occlusion(v, f, v, n, 50)`

Do you know how i could get the facet centroids and the facet normals?
You said that you've used it yourself, how did you achieve it? :)

Comment: The easiest way to calculate the centroid is to just average the 3 vertices